# how to add Dictionary inside an array?

Tags: ios

```
2015-10-01 12:05:32.073 arrayss[1206:30600]  elements in  array= (
    ramki,
        (
        ramakrishna,
        praveen,
        prabhakar,
        ramu,
        ravi
    ),
    name,
        {
        name1 = ramki;
        name2 = praveen;
        name3 = prabhakar;
        name4 = ramu;
        name5 = ravi;
    },
    Employee
)
```

i want to print

```
{
(
        name1 = ramki;
        name2 = praveen;
        name3 = prabhakar;
        name4 = ramu;
        name5 = ravi;
)
},
```

like this help me for that

Comment: Please try formatting the question in a more understandable way. Use code blocks, paragraphs, etc. At the moment it is unreadable and unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

```
[myArray addObjectsFromArray:[dict objectForKey:@"Added"]];
```

I recommend you learn to use the documentation, as this is clearly documented in the NSArray documentation.

On the other hand, if you want to add the whole dictionary to the array, you can use:

```
[myArray addObjects:youDictionary];
```

Comment: I doubt `addObjectsFromArray` is documented in the `NSArray` class reference.